# larger GPU memories, but less epoch

Tags: deep-learning, gpu

Now I'm training deeplearning model with python.
Recently, I changed my GPU Titan X Rtx 3090 but, epoch is not running enough.
At Titan x envrionment, the model runs 12 epoch.
But at Rtx 3090 environment, it only trains 6.
I set all parameters to exactly same.

Do you know why?

Comment: Do you have any EarlyStopping activated? If yes, try disabling it.